# restrict perl to do memory allocation from a fixed range of memory

Tags: perl

I have a C program with perl running as a thread. I would like to restrict the perl interpreter to use memory from a chunk that I pre-allocated (about 2GB). Wonder if it's possible and how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to modify Perl to add your own allocator. On the plus side, Perl already indirects memory allocation (to support different allocators on different platforms), so this would be relatively easy.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, it's good to know perl can have different memory allocators.

Comment: Won't stop C libraries (e.g. XML::LibXML) from allocating their own memory. It would be far easier to run `perl` in a  separate process and limit the process size at the OS level.

Comment: Very good point. Agree with your recommendation of OS level of limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain there is no way to do that in a normal Perl binary, but all perl's memory allocation code is nicely packaged in the `malloc.c` file in the source code. That file also has lots of comments on how Perl's memory allocation works under the hood. It's shouldn't be too hard to create a locally modified perl that does what you want, I think.

Comment: Thanks @calle-dybedahl for pointing it out this file. Never looked into perl internals.